# What is the preferred pattern for authentication in React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-redux, react-navigation

I know there's a few ways to handle this but I'm wondering if there's a preferred or recommended pattern for this that scales well with larger complex apps?
My login process consists of 3 screens or views currently and
my environment consists of React Native, Redux, React Navigation tied to Redux, and Redux Sagas.

Pattern 1:
In my root component I check the authenticated state and return a Login component or return my AppWithNavigationState component.
Problem here is that I have to emulate 3 separate screens for my app flow within one Login component, which is fine with Reacts architecture but creates a lot of messy conditional logic with sub components.

Pattern 2:
My root component just returns my AppWithNavigationState and my startup saga redirects the app to a Login Screen if the user is not authenticated.  Upon successful login the navigation stack is reset to my home screen.
The problem with this idea is whichever screen is your default screen, you will redirect to a different screen depending on authenticated state.  I haven't been able to find a good way of setting the default screen dynamically on app load in the Navigator.

Comment: Why are you not able to navigate to the specific screen depening on authenticated state after login success  from the saga?

Comment: @agent_hunt I can and do.  What I was referring to was dynamically setting the initial screen attribute in the stack navigator so that I start on the correct screen initially, depending on my users state.

Comment: ok. One way to overcome is to use a SplashScreen as the initial screen if that fits your use case.

Comment: @agent_hunt I do use a splash screen for that purpose.  I don't have a problem making this scenario work, I'm more interested in which pattern is the "React" way or which is the recommended way, and why.  My current design is using pattern 2 but my gut tells me pattern 1 is the React way based on it's top down architecture.

Comment: I am not sure if there is "the react way".  Maybe react-router v4 style of routing can help in pattern1.   It is difficult to do that with react navigation or in the mobile use case. From a redux-saga point of view, all side effects and complex orchestration are done inside sagas keeping the logic in components to a minimum which I would personally prefer.